# Does the method need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I need to decide if the following method requires synchronization or not in a multi-threaded environment and why?

```
public class MultiMain 
{

 public int add(int a,int b)
 {

  int r=a+b;
  return r;
 }

}
```

I am new to multi-threading.I do not feel there is any need for synchronization there is no shared resource here but I am not sure about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To the right of the text box when you're asking a question there's a box, **How to Format**. Worth a read.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not need to synchronize that method.  There is no shared state between threads, so it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

No synchronization is needed for that method, because it doesn't have side-effects, i.e. it doesn't touch any class/instance field, and doesn't deal with any object.